# File ended while scanning use of \textit

Tags: errors

I tried deleting the aux file but that did not work, there is no } or $ missing. 
Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
\begin{document}

\title{\textbf{Economía de las organizaciones} - Universidad de San Andr\'es\\ Resoluci\'on del examen}
\author{Anahid Bauer}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\begin{enumerate}
\item \textit{Property Rights + Multitasking}

\textit{Considere el siguiente modelo de Principal- Agente. El timing es como sigue: (1) las partes asignan el control de un \'unico derecho de decisi\'on, $d \in D$; (2)el agente escoge una acci\'on $a \in A$; (3) la acci\'on y el estado de la naturaleza $(s \in {1, ..., S\})$ son p\'ublicamente observados; (4)se toma la desici\'on; y (5)los pagos $U_P(a,s,d)$ y $U_A(a,s,d)$ son recibidos por el Principal y el Agente, respectivamente.}

\textit{La asignaci\'on del derecho de decisi\'on es contratable en la etapa (1). La acci\'on (multidimensional)}$a=(a_1,a_2)$\textit{ no es nunca contratable, y $c(a_1, a_2)=(a_1^2 + a_2^2)/2$, donde $a_i \geq 0$, y $c(\bullet)$ es la funci\'on de costo del agente.}\textit{La decisi\'on $d\in D$ es contratable en la etapa (4) pero no antes. En la etapa (4), las partes eligen la decisi\'on a trav\'es de una negociaci\'on a la Nash, con id\'enticos poderes de negociacion. El pago neto de cada parte es su pago bruto recibido en la etapa (5), m\'as o menos toda la transferencia hecha en las etapas (1) o (4), menos $c(a)$ en el caso del agente. Las partes son neutrales al riesgo y no tienen restricciones financieras.}

\textit{Las decisiones son $d \in \{d_{P1}, d_{A1}, ..., d_{Ps}, d_{As}, ..., d_{PS}, d_{AS}\}$, donde $d_{ij}$ denota la decisi\'on tomada por la parte $i$ en el estado $j$, $i=$ P(rincipal), A(gente), $j=1,..., s,..., S$. Para un par $(a,s)$ dado, las decisiones relevantes son $d_{Ps}$ y $d_{As}$, como sigue:}

\begin{align*}
U_P(a,s, d_{Ps}&=f_1a_1+f_2a_2+K_P\\
U_A(a,s,d_{Ps})&=0\\
U_P(a,s, d_{As}&=g_1a_1+g_2a_2\\
U_A(a,s,d_{As})&=h_1a_1+h_2a_2+K_A\\
U_P(a,s, d)&=U_A(a,s,d)=0 \forall d \notin \{d_{Ps}, d_{As}\}\\
\end{align*}

\textit{Suponga que $f_i,g_i$ y $h_i\geq0$. Suponga tambi\'en que $K_P>0$ es lo suficientemente grande como para que $U_P(a,s, d_{Ps}>U_P(a,s, d_{As}$ para todos los $(a,s)$ relevantes, pero que $K_A>0$ es tal que $U_A(a,s, d_{As}+U_P(a,s, d_{As}>U_P(a,s, d_{Ps}$ para todos los $(a,s)$ relevantes.}


\begin{enumerate}
\item  \textit{Dado $(a,s)$, ?`cu\'al es la decisi\'on eficiente,} $d \in \{d_{P1}, \{d_{A1},..., \{d_{Ps}, \{d_{As}, ... \{d_{PS}, \{d_{AS}\}$

\item \textit{Si el Agente recibe el derecho de decisi\'on en la etapa (1), ?`}

\item 
\end{enumerate}

\item 
\end{enumerate}

\end{enumerate}

\begin{Large}
\textbf{References}
\end{Large}
\begin{itemize}

\item 

\end{itemize}

\textbf{Realic\'e el trabajo requerido por este examen sin ning\'un tipo de ayuda}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Please condense your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) in order to isolate the error, first. People typically don't want to sift through lines and lines of code.

Comment: There is one `\end{enumerate}` too much in your code.

Comment: TeX's error message includes the start of the argument of `\textit`: "Considere el siguiente modelo..." This pins down *exactly* which `\textit` is at fault.

Answer (score 9):

In your first `\textit{}` you have written `\}`. Adding a whitespace solves your error. Have a look on what you really wanted to do with that slash.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\begin{document}
\textit{$(\in {1, ..., S\ })$}
\end{document}
```

I guess you wanted to have the numbers in brackets? So add an other slash to the earlier `{`.

```
$\in \{1, \dots, S\}$
```